# Google Sheet auto-populate new rows with True or False based on current date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have the following formula to check if today's date is greater than or equal to the start of the year and I have copied it on a column along with existing rows

`IF(NOW() >= DATE(2020,01,01),"TRUE","FALSE")`

I want to be able to auto-populate this for newer rows maybe by ArrayFormula or Google script and I will appreciate any form of assistance. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A),NOW() >= DATE(2020,1,1),""))
```

replace range `A2:A` with range where you store data.

Comment: Hi, I don't get it. Would you explain this formula? What is LEN(A2:A) for? What is it testing in this IF formula?

Comment: I suppose len(a2:a) is here just to test if a cell is empty. not(isblank(a2:a)), would make it more clear.

Comment: @KrzysztofDołęgowski Yes, you are right, this condition ensures that only the cells for which data are entered in the relevant ```A2:A``` will be filled. I.e. if ```LEN(A2)``` is greater than 0, then the ```IF``` function interprets it as ```TRUE``` and returns ```NOW()>DATE ...```, if ```LEN(A2)``` is 0 then returns ""

Answer (score 1):

It's  very easy, please see this  youtube video for this
https://youtu.be/7DFr4toDyc8

```
var current_date=new Date();
if(current_date >= activecell.getValue()){
 activecell.offset(0, 1).setValue("True");
} else {
 activecell.offset(0, 1).setValue("False");
}
```